# pip install fail - WinError 10061

Tags: windows, pip, installation, python-3.6

Good Morning,

When attempting to install Python packages using "pip install ", I get the following error:

[pip install error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv89c.png)

The solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459747/pip-install-is-not-working) works for most packages. Unfortunately, packages like [usaddress](https://pypi.org/project/usaddress/), which download additional data during the installation process will result in the following error if the whl/tar is installed locally:

[pip install error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgmUV.png)

I believe this is due to a firewall issue, so the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437701/winerror-10061-no-connection-could-be-made) did not apply in this case, but may be helpful to others.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

*edit: I should have also mentioned that I updated my pip version this morning, after the installation failed.

---

Python version:

> Python 3.6.4 | Anaconda, Inc. | (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Which version of Python are you working on?

Comment: Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: Try upgrading pip and then use "pip install usaddress". If still, it doesn't work, then my suggestion would be to check it installing on Anaconda Python 3.5.2 version because I also faced some issues on installation in Python 3.6.4, so I downgraded Python and Python 3.5.2 is working well & In fact, usaddress was also installed perfectly in it.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. In addition to verifying an up-to-date pip, I tried installing the usaddress whl on Python 3.5.2, but was getting the same error message as before.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. The issued turned out to be that although I downloaded and tried to pip install usaddress, that particular library had a few dependencies that also needed to be installed.

In the "pip install error 2" example from my question, where I tried to install a local copy of usaddress downloaded from pypi.org, you can see a red sentence at the bottom of the screenshot which says, "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement future>=0.14". It means that I need to also install a package called "future", of version greater than or equal to 0.14. I went on to pypi.org, and was able to download and pip install the future package.

I found that some libraries have many dependencies, so it can take a few minutes to keep downloading and installing dependencies, but it was an effective way to get around the firewall.

I hope this saves somebody else some time!