# Python selenium: WinError 10053 - host is shutting connection down

Tags: python, windows, selenium, firefox, network-programming

I started messing around with Python networking using selenium on Firefox. Unfortunately, I keep getting "**ConnectionAbortedError**: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine".

However, this only happens when running *some* commands, and it only happens the first time I run them. If execute the command a second time right after that, it works. (See below for a minimal example.)

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472876/why-is-host-aborting-connection), but being a networking newbie I'm having a hard time applying the solution to my situation. **How do I prevent the connection from shutting down?**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```py
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com/')

searchfield = browser.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")  # Runs without issues
searchfield.get_attribute("value")  # Produces WinError 10053
searchfield.get_attribute("value")  # Returns '' as it should
```

**EDIT:** It seems the error only occurs, when I execute the command in the shell, rather than saving and running the whole script. Nonetheless, it's pretty annoying.

Comment: what version of `geckodriver` do you have? this similar bug https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/713 suggests upgrading to `0.21.0` release of geckodriver if you don't have it already.

Comment: I downloaded it yesterday, so it's probably as up to date as it can be. I tried to reproduce the error mentioned in the link, but it threw me a different one (WinError 10061).

Comment: Not sure why getting different messages, that one related to not getting any connection [WinError 10061 - No Connection Could be made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437701/winerror-10061-no-connection-could-be-made)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the same problem, my config is:
 Firefox 60.0.2 (64 bits)
 ; geckodriver 0.21.0 ( 64 bits)
 ; selenium 3.12.0

I resolved this problem by downgrade geckodriver to 0.20.1 ( 64 bits)

Comment: Saved my day! I was misled by https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/713 into thinking geckodriver 0.21.0 is the one to use.

Comment: Can confirm, this seems to have fixed the problem for me.  With 21.0 I could get a URL immediately after opening a browser, but a subsequent call to get() would inevitably fail with a 10053 error.  I could usually then get() more times successfully, but every now and then I'd get another 10053.  Downgrading to 0.20.1 has alleviated the symptom as described.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried solutions that were mentioned here but nothing helped me. In the end, it was a very simple solution:

copy the script and the geckodriver to a different folder, and then run it from there. I suppose that in the folder where I always worked I had logs that generated conflicts and that's why this solution worked.